# Why is the Dueling fighting style adding such a big bonus to this damage roll on D&D Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, fighting-style, dnd-beyond

I've created a character in D&D Beyond. He's a level 4 half-elf fighter. Here's the character sheet:

[image: Character sheet img 1]
[image: Character sheet img 2]

The character has a longsword and D&D Beyond has calculated the damage roll on this to be **1d8+12**. The +12 bonus seems too big according to my calculations. I'm calculating the roll like this:

1. The base roll for a longsword is **1d8**
2. I add my strength modifier so that's **+4**
3. I have dueling as my fighting style speciality so that's **+2** because I'm wiedling the longsword with one hand

So I calculate the roll as **1d8+6**. Where is D&D Beyond getting the extra +6 bonus from?

If I change the fighting style from dueling to say, archery, the bonus drops to +4, which seems correct. Why does the dueling fighting style add such a huge bonus?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### It is a bug

Well, it is clear that it is a bug. Your calculation is right: it should be +6 damage. You can ask about bugs on D&D Beyond [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support).

### Similar Issue

In the first page, there is a similar issue in [this thread](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support/73617-incorrect-attack-bonus-2nd-level-ranger-with-13).

One staff member has responded:

> **Unfortunately there is currently a way to select the fighting style option multiple times, though we plan to resolve it.**
>
> To resolve it, please go edit the fighting style and move it from ARCHERY to CHOOSE AN OPTION and then repeat until it stays on CHOOSE AN OPTION.
>
> Then select the desired fighting style as normal.

So, it seems it is a problem with Fighting Styles and, when you select it, you may, by accident, select it more than once, so, instead of one instance of "Dueling", it seems you got 4 instances, stacking a bonus of +8.

Comment: That fixes it, thank you. This also explains why I had to click 'Dueling' on the dropdown multiple times for it to stay selected.